# How to select every 2nd element of an array in a for loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to improve my JavaScript skills. Using a for loop I want to select every second element (for example I want to make them bold or italic). I know I can do this using CSS3 and the `nth-child` selector, but as I said, I'm trying to improve my JS skills and I want to do this using a `for` loop and no `foreach` loop or another JS loop type. I'm new in JS.

edit:I want to add all element but i just want to pick up every second element to make them bold or italic

```js
var myList = document.getElementById('myList');
var addList = ["Python", "C", "C++", "Ruby", "PHP", "Javascript", "Go", "ASP", "R"];

for (var i = 0; i < addList.length; i++) {
  var newLi = document.createElement("li");

  newLi.innerHTML = addList[i];
  myList.appendChild(newLi);
}
```

```html
<ul id="myList"></ul>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `modulo(%)`operator to get every `2nd element` in loop and add `fontStyle` to it:

```js
var myList = document.getElementById('myList');
var addList = ["Python", "C", "C++", "Ruby", "PHP", "Javascript", "Go", "ASP", "R"];

for (var i = 0; i < addList.length; i++) {
  var newLi = document.createElement("li");
  newLi.innerHTML = addList[i];
  if(i % 2 == 0){
  newLi.style.fontStyle = "italic";
  newLi.innerHTML = "<strong>"+addList[i]+"</strong>";
  }

  myList.appendChild(newLi);
}
```

```html
<ul id="myList"></ul>
```

Comment: oo thank you this is great so can I added code instead of css for example <strong>element</strong>?

Comment: how ?    if(i % 2 == 0){
        newLi.innerHTML = "<strong>".addList[i]+"</strong>";

    } this is not work

Answer (score 5):

In your for loop, instead of increasing `i` by 1, increase `i` by two on every iteration with `i+=2`.

Updated code:

```js
var myList = document.getElementById('myList');
var addList = ["Python", "C", "C++", "Ruby", "PHP", "Javascript", "Go", "ASP", "R"];

for (var i = 0; i < addList.length; i+=2) {
  var newLi = document.createElement("li");

  newLi.innerHTML = addList[i];
  myList.appendChild(newLi);
}
```

```html
<ul id="myList"></ul>
```

Comment: And if it's really every second element, start at 1, not 0.

Comment: no.this is not answer that i looking for i want to add all element by i just want to pick up every second element to make them bold or italic

Answer (score 2):

In your `for` loop, instead of `i++`, use `i += 2`.

Comment: And start `i` at `1` and not `0`, I guess.

Comment: It does not directly follow the question.

Comment: no.this is not answer that i looking for i want to add all element by i just want to pick up every second element to make them bold or italic

Answer (score 2):

You could add something like this to the loop body:

```
if (i % 2 == 1) {
    // whatever you need to do to make it bold or italic
}
```

This will be called for every odd value of `i`.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use i+=2 in place of i++ in your loop

Comment: no.this is not answer that i looking for i want to add all element by i just want to pick up every second element to make them bold or italic

Comment: okay @ani_css then in loop put a new var equal to i ..then add 2 to that new variable then you'll get every second i

Comment: i use this   if(i % 2 == 1){
        newLi.innerHTML =+"<strong>"+addList[i]+"</strong>";

    } but nothing happend

Answer (score 1):

To add all elements and pick up every 2nd element, use the modulo operator `%` in `if` statement: `i % 2 == 0` and change the `fontStyle`.

Updated code:

```js
var myList = document.getElementById('myList');
var addList = ["Python", "C", "C++", "Ruby", "PHP", "Javascript", "Go", "ASP", "R"];

for (var i = 0; i < addList.length; i+=2) {
  var newLi = document.createElement("li");
  
  if (i % 2 == 0) {
    // make bold
    newLi.style.fontStyle = "bold"
    // make italic
    newLi.style.fontStyle = "italic"
  }

  newLi.innerHTML = addList[i];
  myList.appendChild(newLi);
}
```

```html
<ul id="myList"></ul>
```

Comment: no.this is not answer that i looking for i want to add all element by i just want to pick up every second element to make them bold or italic